# How to set 'Assigned to' in TFS Work item through code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to create a workitem through code. Currently I am using the following code to set Assigned to.

```
wi.Fields["System.AssignedTo"].Value = "TfsUser display name";
```

Currently I am setting the TFS user display name. I have following doubts.

Is Display name in TFS is unique?

If not how to set a unique name like account name as assigned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display new is the only value that you can use to at this field in a work item.

You can query the user identity system and retrieve the display name from TFS for the user that you want.

Comment: Is OP right about the doubts? I've found a similar problem someone had [here](http://codermike.blogspot.com.tr/2014/03/tfs-multiple-identities-found-matching.html). And [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.teamfoundationidentity.displayname.aspx), msdn says that tfs 2012 will not try to disambiguate identities from display name. But like you said, "System.AssignedTo" field only accepts DisplayName. Is it possible that, if there is 2 users with same displayName, unintended user is assigned to field?

Comment: I tested with VIsual Studio Online and the Display Name is NOT unique. So OP is correct with its doubts.

Comment: You should encourage users not to have the same display name.

Comment: But my point still holds, the API is flawed and there seems to be no workaround.

Comment: Have you actually experienced an issue? Coz i have not in 8 years of playing with the API?

Comment: I think with Visual Studio Online and the ability to add any Microsoft Account, this will lead to problems sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
newWorkItem.Fields[CoreField.AssignedTo].Value ="person";
```