# TFS could not save Workitem

Tags: c#, tfs

I am using Team Foundation Server 2015 update 3.
I am trying to create workitems from my C# project.
I am creating workitems using tfs api from   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.

And it cannot validate workitem before saving.

Problem with the field Assigned To.
I have tried to put values like "Alexey Solovyev"(My display name), ASolovyev(login) and DOMAIN\ASolovyev.
In all  cases i have a message in Arraylist of ValidationErrors "InvalidListValue".

What is wrong here?

```
     public static bool Save(WorkItem wi)
        {
            ArrayList validationErrors = wi.Validate();
            if (validationErrors.Count == 0)
            {
                try {
                    wi.Save();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    wi.Fields["Conditions_plain"].Value = "Exception Message";
                    wi.Save();
                }

                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }



  public static bool createTask()
        {
            Project proj = _wiStore.Projects["MyProject"];
            WorkItem wi = new WorkItem(proj.WorkItemTypes["Task"]);

            wi.Fields["Title"].Value = "AUTOGENERATED!";
            wi.Fields["Assigned to"].Value = "Alexey Solovyev";

            return Save(wi);
        }
```

Comment: Where is your sample code?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641279/how-to-set-assigned-to-in-tfs-work-item-through-code) SO question helps

Comment: I know my display name and i tried to put it into Assigned To.

Comment: Do you have duplicated display name?

Comment: No i have not. This case is not only with my user.

Comment: What's the entire display name in TFS Web Portal after you sign in?

Comment: Entire display name is Alexey Solovyev. Actually i am trying to create a task and put into "assigned to" this name. But it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .net API, it's suggest you use REST API as you are using TFS 2015. REST API is much easier to [create a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item):

```
PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemTypeName}?api-version={version}

Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": xxxxx
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
        "value": xxxxx
    },
]
```

If I use the duplicated display name, I'll get error "The field 'Assigned To' contains the value 'xxxxx' that is not in the list of supported values".